# Does setting "idea.jars.nocopy" in idea.properites have any negative impact?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I noticed that `C:\Users\$USER\.IntelliJIdea12\system` folder has a huge size when using a big maven project (300+ sub-modules).

Would setting `idea.jars.nocopy` to true decrease the disk usage in this folder ? I believe doing an 'invalidate Caches' also cleans up this folder.

Do you think that setting this param to true has a negative impact ?

The idea.properties file has the following to say about this param:

---

`IDE copies library jars to prevent their locking. If copying is not desirable, specify "true"`

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will reduce the disk usage, but the locking can occur (you will not be able to replace the jar files in the project when the application or IntelliJ IDEA is running).

If you don't plan replacing the jars and locking doesn't break your workflow, feel free to set this option to `true`.

Mac/Linux users do not have the locking issue, it's Windows specific.

Comment: Linux users had faced this locking issue too when used NTFS due to [bug 202297](http://b.android.com/202297).